# Reverses lines from a file given parameter

Tags: c, string, function, file

I have to write a function void reverse_file(FILE* file) that reads lines from the parameter file one line at the time into a local character array buffer whose size is #defined as a preprocessor constant MAXLINE. For each line, this function calls the previous reverse_string function to reverse the line, then writes the reversed line in standard output.

I have the reverse_string method

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_String(char* str);
int main()
{
    char str [256];
    strcpy_s(str, "Hello");
    reverse_String(str);
    return 0;
}
void reverse_String(char* str)
{
    int i, j;
    char temp;
    i=j=temp=0;

    j=strlen(str)-1;
    for (i=0; i<j; i++, j--)
    {
        temp=str[i];
        str[i]=str[j];
        str[j]=temp;
    }
    printf("%s",str);
}
```

I just need help with the reverse_file(FILE* file) part.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Suppose you have a file of three lines: `abc`, `def`, `ghi`.  Do you need to output `cba`, `fed`, `ihg`, or `ghi`, `def`, `abc`, or perhaps `ihg`, `fed`, `cba`?  Regardless of what the requisite output is, you need to look up standard C [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read lines of input.  Then you call your reverse string function when appropriate.  Note that it is usually better to separate the output from the reversal.

Comment: Also, `printf(str)` is bad — very bad.  You should use `printf("%s\n", str)` or `puts(str)`.  The danger is that the string you're printing will contain `%` sequences, and you didn't provide arguments for `printf()` to process for those `%s` sequences.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the second one. abc becomes cba

Comment: You seem to be missing your `#define`. You look like you intend to give the *maximum characters* allowed in each line as a define. You will want something like `#define MAXC 256` (immediately under the `#include ...` statements, then `char str [MAXC] = "";` to make use of it. (note: you want to use `defines` instead of *magic numbers* (e.g. `256`) scattered through your code. You can also use an `enum` to define the same constant instead of `#define`, e.g. `enum { MAXC = 256 };`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin totally forgot about that, thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_String(char* str)
{
    int i, j;
    char temp;
    i=j=temp=0;

    j=strlen(str)-1;
    for (i=0; i<j; i++, j--) {
        temp=str[i];
        str[i]=str[j];
        str[j]=temp;
    }
    printf("%s",str);
 }

 void reverse_File(FILE* file) {
     char* line;
     size_t len = 0;
     ssize_t read;

     while ((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1) {
        reverse_String(line);
     }
 }

int main(void) {

    FILE * fp;

    fp = fopen("Maze.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    reverse_File(fp);
}
```

Comment: except you are not trimming the `'\n'` from each `line` as read by `getline` which means each reversed line will begin with a newline. You should always remove the trailing `'\n'` or `'\r\n'` (DOS/windows) when using *line-oriented* input.

Comment: Pretty neat.  Couple of minor problems.  (1) You should should ensure that `line` can be passed safely to `free()` (per [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)
: _The application shall ensure that `*lineptr` is a valid argument that could be passed to the `free()` function._), so setting `line` to 0 is a good idea.  (2) You should free the memory that was (probably) allocated by `getline()`, even if the file was empty so the first read operation returns `-1` (it doesn't return EOF, interestingly enough).  And you need to handle line endings too.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: for text files on WIndows, the I/O subsystem should convert trailing CRLF to just NL (aka LF) on input, and replace NL with CRLF on output.  If the file came from Windows to Unix, or if the file is opened for binary I/O, then you need to worry about the line endings if it really is a text file.

Comment: Well excellent - I learned something new about that mysterious operating system today. Thank you, so windows will get rid of the `'\r'` for a normal file during I/O and it just the ones that are copied windows->linux that will have the `'\r'` present when read on Linux. That explains the absence of questions related to extraneous carriage-returns `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You already have a fine answer, but there are a few subtle points to consider. If you are using *line-oriented* input methods (`fgets` or `getline`), you should remove the `'\n'` or `'\r\n'` (DOS/windows) line-ending read and included in the original line by either `fgets` or `getline`. (this is why you have an initial blank line in the output of the original file).

A simple way to remove the line-endings is to simply overwrite the first of either line-ending encountered with a *nul-terminating* character. To do this, your main program logic will look like:

```
while (fgets (str, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line */
    rmcrlf (str);                   /* trim \r or \n  */
    strrev (str);                   /* reverse string */
    printf ("%s\n", str);           /* output reverse */
}
```

Your `rmcrlf` (remove carriage-return line-feed) could look like the following:

```
/** stip trailing newlines and carraige returns by overwriting with
 *  null-terminating char. 's' is modified in place.
 */
void rmcrlf (char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) return;          /* validate not NUL and not empty */
    char *p = strpbrk (s, "\r\n");  /* locate first line-ending char  */
    *p = 0;                         /* set to nul-terminating char    */
}
```

(note: you could use `strlen` (or a pointer and loop) to find the end of the string and work backwards, but `strpbrk` allows you to search for either `'\n'` or `'\r'` in the forward direction without needing to find the end and work backwards)

You can then reverse your string in place in the same way (but using `strrchr` to find the end instead of `strlen`)

```
/** strrev - reverse string 's' in place.
 *  The original string is not preserved.
 *  If 's' is not valid, no action taken.
 */
void strrev (char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) { /* validate s not NUL and not empty */
        printf ("strrev() error: invalid string\n");
        return;
    }

    char tmp;
    char *begin = s, *end = strrchr (s, 0) - 1;

    while (end > begin) {
        tmp = *end;
        *end-- = *begin;
        *begin++ = tmp;
    }
}
```

You can put all the pieces together as follows. This is simply another way to approach the same task. Note: the following code uses an `enum` instead of a `#define` to set define the constant (just to show the alternate method). Also note: that the code will read from the file given as the first argument (or from `stdin` by default, if no filename is given):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXC = 256 };

void strrev (char *s);
void rmcrlf (char *s);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char str[MAXC] = "";
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file is open */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (str, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line */
        rmcrlf (str);                   /* trim \r or \n  */
        strrev (str);                   /* reverse string */
        printf ("%s\n", str);           /* output reverse */
    }

    if (fp != stdin)         /* close file (if not stdin) */
        fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}

/** strrev - reverse string 's' in place.
 *  The original string is not preserved.
 *  If 's' is not valid, no action taken.
 */
void strrev (char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) { /* validate s not NUL and not empty */
        printf ("strrev() error: invalid string\n");
        return;
    }

    char tmp;
    char *begin = s, *end = strrchr (s, 0) - 1;

    while (end > begin) {
        tmp = *end;
        *end-- = *begin;
        *begin++ = tmp;
    }
}

/** stip trailing newlines and carraige returns by overwriting with
 *  null-terminating char. 's' is modified in place.
 */
void rmcrlf (char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) return;
    char *p = strpbrk (s, "\r\n");
    *p = 0;
}
```

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/strtorev.txt
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr
ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQR
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/strrev_line <dat/strtorev.txt
rqp onm lkj ihg fed cba
RQP ONM LKJ IHG FED CBA
```

(note: as Johnathan asked in the comment, you can either reverse the line as shown above, or you can reverse each word (e.g. `cba fed ihg...`) make sure you have correctly stated what you need to do, if not we can help further).

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Just cleaning up a few loose ends. Good luck with your coding.